# How do I target a div that is below another div with css

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a simple set up but I am not sure when I hover over the second div how to target the fist div. Below is an example I can't get the second div to target the first div on hover. Any help would be great.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">Some text.</div>
  <div id="two">Some more text.</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container #two {
  width: 50vw;
}

#container #two:hover {
  width: 90vw;
}

#container #two:hover + #one {
  width: 10vw;
}
```

Comment: It does — not — work in this direction.

Comment: try this for your css `#container {
  display: flex;
}

#one,
#two {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s;
  padding:20px;
}

#two {
  background: green;
}

#one:hover,
#two:hover {
  flex: 5;
}`

Comment: I saw you added jquery as tag, you can bind [JQuery .hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to implement this. like `$( "#two" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);`

Comment: @Matt `#container #two:hover + #one { width:10vw;}` should be '#container #two:hover + #one { right:-40vw;}' I was messing with flex but could not get that to work. Any other suggestions? I in my code I am using two background images.